# Client socket stops working after client closes program suddenly

Tags: python-sockets

Server code starts to listening. When I do F5 in client and wait, the code runs just fine. If I try F5 again, in the middle of previous attempt of connection, the client program can't establish a connection (s == None), which I need to work around, specially because whenever I run client again, it stays showing the same problem to establish connection. In other to work back again, I need to restart server program.
In other to debug, the way I know it's not working properly, the IDLE prints "q"s 20 times and then

> could not open socket
>
> Can't read result.

I accept any constructive criticism about my coding. Programming's been just a hobby for me. Here are my both codes:

#### server code

```
import socket
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import psycopg2 as psy

print("server is on!")
HOST = None
PORT = 50007

process = []

def checkin_room(room, passw, user, ip, port):
    print("main:checkin_room")
    conn = psy.connect("host=localhost dbname=pychat user=root password=codigo64")
    cr = conn.cursor()
    cr.execute("select * from rooms where name = '%s';")
    row = cr.fetchone()
    print("main: here")
    if row == None:
        cr.execute("insert into rooms (name,hashpw) values ('%s','%s');"%(room,passw))
        cr.execute("select id from rooms where name = '%s';"%(room))
        rid = cr.fetchone()[0]
        cr.execute("insert into users (rid,name,ip,port) values (%d,'%s','%s',%d);"%(rid,user,ip,port))
        print("new room")
        return 1 # room created
    else:
        cr.execute("select * from rooms where name = '%s' and hashpw = '%s';"%(room,passw))
        row = cr.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            print("wrong password for room")
            return 0 # wrong password
        else:
            cr.execute("select ip, port from users where rid = %d and ip != '%s';"%(row[0],ip))
            row = cr.fetchall()
            if row == None:
                print("no users in room")
                return []
            print("other users in room")
            return row # correct password: return ip and ports of users from room
    

def check_socket():
    print("Socket's being checked.")
    while True:
        s = None
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                                      socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
            af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
            try:
                s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
            except OSError as msg:
                s = None
                continue
            try:
                s.bind(sa)
                s.listen(1)
            except OSError as msg:
                s.close()
                s = None
                continue
            break
##        if s is None:
##            print('could not open socket')
##            sys.exit(1)
        if s != None:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            try:
                ip, port = addr
            except:
                print("problem: ",addr)
                s.close()
                s = None
                continue
            with conn:
                print('Connected by', addr)
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    cmd = eval(data.decode("utf-8"))
                    if cmd[0] == "checkin":
                        ret = checkin_room(cmd[1],cmd[2],cmd[3],ip,port)
                        conn.sendall(str(ret).encode("utf-8"))
            s.close()
                    

process.append(mp.Process(target = check_socket))
process[-1].start()
print("process started...")
time.sleep(1)
print("Command line ready for use.")
while True:
    cmd = input()
    if cmd == "end":
        for p in process:
            p.terminate()
        break
print("Program's over.")
```

#### client code

```
import socket, sys

HOST = "123.123.123.123" # fake host
PORT = 50007

ROOM = "ufrj"
PASSW = "fundao"
USER = "coresh"

friends = []


def send_server(host, port, cmd):
    s = None
    print("client: here1")
    for i in range(20):
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
            af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
            try:
                s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
            except socket.error as msg:
                s = None
                continue
            try:
                s.connect(sa)
            except socket.error as msg:
                s.close()
                s = None
                continue
            break
        if s == None:
            print("qq")
        else:
            break
    if s is None:
        print ('could not open socket')
        return
    print("client: here2")
    s.sendall(bytearray(str(cmd).encode("utf-8")))
    print("here3")
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print("here4")
    s.close()
    print("closed")
    return eval(data.decode("utf-8"))


def checkin_room(room, passw, user):
    cmd = ["checkin", room, passw, user]
    ret = send_server(HOST, PORT, cmd)
    
    if ret == 1:
        print("Room's been created.")

    elif ret == 0:
        print("Wrong password.")

    elif type(ret) == list:
        if ret == []:
            print("Only you in the room.")
        else:
            friends += ret

    else:
        print("Can't read result.")
        
checkin_room(ROOM, PASSW, USER)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing when you press F5 again is that you are cutting off the program without closing the socket first. This causes it to hang and you can't use the socket again. Get the client to `s.close()` before restarting the program. This will close the socket fully and stop the socket from hanging.

In regard into how you code, try putting a blank line in between each line of code. This will help you read and debug code.